# Regression analysis with max value

Tags: regression, python, predictive-models, numpy

I am trying to find the best curve that will describe my data. my data are stored in numpy arrays of `t` and `dur` they are both in values only from 0-1. However the best fit I get according to R**2 score is this yellow line with score of 0.979388 which doesn't fit my data because it is way off from expected values when it is well above 1 in Y axis:

[image]

Is there any other way to properly validate the best fit score? Or is here a posibility to have a ceiling for max value in regression models? Or somewhat exclude this 'overfitting' curves? I need to create multiple of these regression on automated basis so I can't decide myself as a user what is the best fit.

```
t = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.33695652173913043, 0.010869565217391304, 1.0, 0.018518518518518517, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.005076142131979695, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.03225806451612903, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 1.0]
dur = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9999999999999998, 0.2688679245283018, 0.2688679245283018, 1.0, 0.46692607003891046, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4444444444444444, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.34210526315789475, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4714285714285715, 0.4714285714285715, 1.0]

#polynomial curve fitting
mymodel1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t, dur, 1))
mymodel2 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t, dur, 2))
mymodel3 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t, dur, 3))
mymodel4 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t, dur, 4))

#polynomial score
p1 = r2_score(dur, mymodel1(t))
p2 = r2_score(dur, mymodel2(t))
p3 = r2_score(dur, mymodel3(t))               
p4 = r2_score(dur, mymodel4(t))

#append results of R**2 to list of tuples from which I extract best score
fit = []
fit.append(p1)
fit.append(p2)
fit.append(p3)
fit.append(p4)
fitname = []
fitname.append('p1')
fitname.append('p2')
fitname.append('p3')
fitname.append('p4')

#append best result value
resultValue.append(max(fitTuple,key=lambda item:item[0])[0])

#append best result name
resultName.append(max(fitTuple,key=lambda item:item[0])[1])

#plot values from regression models
myline = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) 
plt.plot(myline, mymodel1(myline),color = "black")
plt.plot(myline, mymodel2(myline),color = "black")
plt.plot(myline, mymodel3(myline),color = "black")
plt.plot(myline, mymodel4(myline),color = "yellow")
```

Comment: The data has so many points with $t=1, dur=1$ that they should be incorporated into the model as a constraint. (Eg the model might optimize among formulas of the form $t=1+a(dur-1)+b(dur-1)^2$ or $dur=1+a(t-1)+b(t-1)^2$.) The best fit under that constraint will likely respect the $(0,1)$ bounds automatically.

Comment: And how is this type of regression called please? How did you found this model?

Comment: These are quadratic models with zero constant coefficient, shifted (or transformed) to $(1,1)$ as the origin. I can’t explain easily how I found this, but I expect that if you fit a more general model of the form $t=\alpha + \beta\, dur + \gamma\, dur^2$ to the data, you will find that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ is not significantly different from $1$, so the fitted general model will not differ significantly from a model of this form.